# Rails 3.1 Use an image without fingerprint hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I have solved a few of my asset pipeline woes, but one of them remains. I have a couple of image_tags, and I want them to refer to the non-fingerprinted/hashed/digested version. Is there a way to force an image_tag (but only one or two, not application-wide) to use the non-digested version of the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [fingerprintless](https://github.com/bluetools/fingerprintless), that should do it.

Answer (score 2):

Use `:digest => false` as an option to `asset_path` within `image_tag`

```
<%= image_tag(asset_path("filename.png", :digest => false)) %>
```